# Animations (GIF) in beamer

Tags: beamer, animations, animate

I have a GIF (file.gif) file that I want to include in my beamer presentaiton. This is what I did:

(1) I created 60 .png files of all the frames of file.gif : file0.png, file1.png,..., file60.png.

(2) I run the following code line:

```
\begin{center}
\animategraphics[loop,controls,width=\linewidth, scale=0.3]{12}{gif_file/file}{0}{60}
\end{center}
```

(3) I did use theses packages : graphics, graphicx, animate.

The result is it shows only the first frame. It's clickable but even so, it does not move.

Comment: As always on this site, please provide a full but minimal exmaple of the code you used, That makes it a lot easier to understand what excactly you were doing and how.

Comment: When updating your question to add a mwe, please also add how you compile your document and which viewer you use.

Comment: Which pdf viewer do you use? Many viewer do not accept this kind of format I think. (to solve that issue, I used a completely different approach not even using pdf, but I had no time to release it in a library)

Comment: I second the comment about the PDF viewer: on Linux, the only two viewers that work for me with animations is `okular` and `pdfpc`.